# Pdf2Html Installation

Tags: installation, pdf2htmlex

I 'm trying to install Pdf2HtmlEx Software on Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS. The repository is not maintained but the sotware is very useful for me.

I installed it on Xubuntu desktop distro and on a docker image but i can't do it on ubuntu server.

It seems that some new versions of pdf2htmlEx library dependencies are not compatible with the last version of the sofware.

Has anyone have de same issue? Could someone tell me how to install it?

I have try with

- [rajeevkannav solution](https://gist.github.com/rajeevkannav/d07f822e209a22d07176)
- [Copying this dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/klokoy/pdf2htmlex/~/dockerfile/)
- [Following Build Installation](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/wiki/Building)

The oficial repo is [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX)

Thank you for know!

Answer (score 0):

## Install m4

wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/m4-1.4.17.tar.gz && tar -xvzf m4-1.4.17.tar.gz
cd m4-1.4.17 && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/m4 && make && make install

## Install poppler dependencies

apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    pkg-config libopenjp2-7-dev libopenjp2-7 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfontforge-dev poppler-data poppler-utils \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

## Install poppler

wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-0.63.0.tar.xz --no-check-certificate &&    tar -xvf poppler-0.63.0.tar.xz
cd poppler-0.63.0/ &&   cmake -DENABLE_XPDF_HEADERS=ON . && make && make install

## Install fontforge dependencies

apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    packaging-dev pkg-config python-dev libpango1.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libxml2-dev \
    libjpeg-dev libtiff-dev uthash-dev libspiro-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

pkg-config --print-provides --cflags --libs poppler

## Install fontforge

git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge.git
cd fontforge/ &&    ./bootstrap && ./configure && make && make install

## Clone and install the pdf2htmlEX git repo

git clone https://github.com/pdf2htmlEX/pdf2htmlEX.git
cd pdf2htmlEX && cmake . && make && make install

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer!

Finally, i have used the docker container that is in the oficial documentation of the package [Docker image (Alpine)].  I couldn't install Pdf2HtmlEx in Ubuntu directly.

The docker container is working really good and i have been using it for six months.